# Salesforce Lead Trigger CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I want to clone the Profile__c record. The lead has a profile__c associated with it. When conversion happens, the Profile_c on the lead is copied to the account created. What I need to do is a deep clone of the Profile__c on the new account  created after the conversion. I am able to copy the profile_c over but cloning throws this error:

Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00QJ0000007dDmHMAU; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, profile: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD, cannot reference converted lead: [] Trigger.profile:, column 1: [] (System Code)

```
trigger profile on Lead (after update) {

Map<Id, Lead> cl = new Map<Id,Lead>();
Lead parent;
List<Contact> clist = new List<Contact>();
Set<Id> convertedids = new Set<Id>();

//list of converted leads
for (Lead t:Trigger.new){
    Lead ol = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.ID);
    if(t.IsConverted == true && ol.isConverted == false)
    {
        cl.put(t.Id, t);
        convertedids.add(t.ConvertedContactId);
    }
}
 Set<Id> leadIds = cl.keySet();  

  List<Profile__c> mp = [select Id, lock__c, RecordTypeId, reason__c, End_Date__c,startus__c , Opportunity__c, Account__c, Lead__c from Profile__c where Lead__c in :leadIds];
  List<ID>AccountIDs = new List<ID>();
  List<Profile__c>clonedList = new list<Profile__c>();
  for (Profile__c mpi:mp){
    parent = cl.get(mpi.Lead__c );
    mpi.opportunity__c = parent.ConvertedOpportunityId;
    mpi.account__c = parent.ConvertedAccountId;
    AccountIDs.add(parent.ConvertedAccountId);
    Profile__c profile = mpi.clone(false,true,false,false);
    clonedList.add(profile);
    mpi.lock__c= true;
    mpi.reason__c= 'Converted';
  }
 update mp;
 insert clonelist
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing insert operation(insert clonelist) in which you are accessing Converted lead Id value in a field. You can't use converted LeadId field in DML operations.
Below is the Sample code that will work-

```
trigger ConvertedLead_Trigger on Lead (after update) {
Map<Id, Lead> cl = new Map<Id,Lead>();
Lead parent;
List<Contact> clist = new List<Contact>();
Set<Id> convertedids = new Set<Id>();

//list of converted leads
for (Lead t:Trigger.new){
    Lead ol = Trigger.oldMap.get(t.ID);
    if(t.IsConverted == true && ol.isConverted == false)
    {
        cl.put(t.Id, t);
        convertedids.add(t.ConvertedContactId);
    }
}
 Set<Id> leadIds = cl.keySet();
     List<ConvertLeadTest__c> mp =[Select Id,Name,Lead__c, Account__c,Opportunity__c from ConvertLeadTest__c where Lead__c in :leadIds];
    List<ConvertLeadTest__c> mp1=new List<ConvertLeadTest__c>();
    List<ConvertLeadTest__c> mp2=new List<ConvertLeadTest__c>();
    for(ConvertLeadTest__c cc:mp)
    {
        if(cl.containsKey(cc.Lead__c))
        {

          cc.Account__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedAccountId;
          cc.Opportunity__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedOpportunityId;
            mp1.add(cc);
            mp2.add(new ConvertLeadTest__c(Account__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedAccountId,Opportunity__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedOpportunityId));
        }
    }

    update mp;
    insert mp2;
}
```

But if you write 
ConvertLeadTest__c(Lead__c=cc.Lead__c,Account__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedAccountId,Opportunity__c=cl.get(cc.Lead__c).ConvertedOpportunityId));
then it will throw error.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks :)

Comment: The problem here is I want to clone the Profile__c record. The lead has a profile__c associated with it so does Account. When conversion happens, the Profile_c on the lead is copied to the account created. What I need to do is clone all fields on Profile__c on the account after the conversion.

Comment: It is possible. You can fetch Profile__c record after lead conversion using trigger and then copy all its field to the account and update that account.

Comment: I am not copying the fields to the account. I am merely associating the profile__c on lead with the account after conversion. In other words, profile__c is relatedlist on both lead and account objects. After conversion, I want to duplicate the profile__c already associated with the lead and associate both with the account.

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to perform any operation on the Lead once the lead is converted.
Anything you do to try o update the converted lead will give you error.

Answer (score 0):

What eventually did it for me was after the conversion, I grabbed the convertedAccountIds. Since I was already copying Profile__c to the account after conversion, I just cloned the profile there and had to set the lead on that profile to null since it can't be updated